# Is there a way to get a string representation of a variable in a dart class?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, I have a class named Task as follows:

```
class Task {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final DateTime date;
  bool isDone;

  Task({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.description = "",
    required this.date,
    this.isDone = false,
  });
}
```

Now I want to map this class to a database table, means for that I need to map every member of the class with a string to create a table. Like this:

```
"CREATE TABLE tasks (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT)"
```

Is there a way in Dart to get a `String` representation of class members, so to avoid declaring additional `static const` members just for the names of these members, and also to avoid hardcoding these names every place I need them. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you are just looking to map your class `Task` to a database table, in that case, you might want to look at some ORM or ORM-like tools such as PostgREST -- https://pub.dev/packages/postgrest

Answer (score 1):

You need some reflection, you can get that from the official mirrors library: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html